# Alphanumeric with floats/decimals

Tags: php, regex

I have the following to strip a string to alphanumeric `a-z0-9`:

```
echo preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/u", '', $text);
```

Works fine. How do I allow it to keep floats, so `10.9` is not stripped to `109`. I tried `/[^[:alnum:][:space:][.]]/u` but didn't work.

It should *not* strip floats, but should strip dots if it isn't a decimal number. So `etc.` should be stripped to `etc`, but `1.5` should stay as `1.5`.

Comment: Extract them, `preg_match('~\d*\.?\d+~', $s, $match)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please post an answer? Do you mean I should extract the numeric values, and then do another `preg_replace()` to strip the rest of the text? There must surely be a way to strip the text and keep floats in one go?

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags. Regex can be language-specific

Comment: @VadimKotov Mixture of English and Japanese characters. (good question btw!)

Comment: @GaryWoods No, I mean programming language ;)

Comment: @VadimKotov Lol, it's PHP.

Comment: Add the `php` tag...

Comment: @trincot I don't think it's relevant to add the php tag because the question is regex related. And it is clear in my example above that I am running the regex within a PHP environment.

Comment: Well, some regex features are language dependent. Not all regexes support `[:alnum:]`, nor do all support look-behind (which I used in the answer), so there is some sense in adding the tag.

Comment: @GaryWoods If you're using PHP syntax to define a regex, you should use [tag:php] tag. This way users can filter questions and watch their favourite tags

Comment: @trincot Aha, that is super interesting and makes sense. Will keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use look-around for checking whether there is no digit before the dot, or there is no digit after it, and only then delete it:

```
echo preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:].]|(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)/u", '', $text);
```